# Summary of percent in Mdx

Tags: mdx

I have a question about summary of percents in Mdx.
I need to take percent value of importer sales from specific category ( like Adidas is 80% of sales in deodorants category), multiplie this value with himself( percent value^2) and then sum for all importers that in this category.
It works for all importers, i get the right values, but when i do the sum of this result- i get the wrong number. 
For example  , i have :

```
57.5472% 
03.6083%
00.000%

=
```

The result is: 94.9034% This is wrong result.

The point is if i take this results to Excel and do autosummmary- i get the right number: 61.1

The code is:

Thank you! Off course:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[temp_HHI_new] --!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

as case when [Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]*[Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory] < 0.001 then 0 
else [Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]*[Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]
end

,
Format_string = '00.0000%' ,

What is wrong?
Thank' a lot and have a good day!

Comment: can you provide the code related to your issue?

Comment: Thank you! Off course:
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[temp_HHI_new] --!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

as case when [Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]*[Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory] < 0.001 then 0 
else [Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]*[Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]
end
,
Format_string = '##.###%' ,

Comment: I am not competend in `mdx`, however I ll help you to format your question so someone who know is able to fully understand your problem and find a solution to it. Please add this chunk of code in your post by editing it.

Comment: Thank you! Off course:
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[temp_HHI_new] --!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

as case when [Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]*[Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory] < 0.001 then 0 
else [Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]*[Measures].[prcnt sale from catgory]
end

,
Format_string = '00.0000%' ,


the result is:

57.5472% 
03.6083%
00.000%

=94.9034%

Comment: @Veronika Can you share your query plz.